# How to fix "Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =>" ESLint error?

Tags: javascript, closures, eslint, idioms

I'm getting this error

```
Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =>"
```

for the code below:

```
let guestBeingEdited = SJ.Event.ListItem.previouslyAddedGuests.filter(
    guest => {
        return guest.id === SJ.Event.ListItem.selectPrevGuest;
    },
);
```

I tried different suggestions [from here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) but couldn't get it fixed. Any suggestions?

Comment: _"I tried different ways..."_ - For example?

Comment: added the example

Comment: _"I had made the mistake of keeping the semicolon."_ ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576332/eslint-error-unexpected-block-statement-surrounding-arrow-body-move-the-retur?noredirect=1#comment110663057_62576363)) -> VtC because it was just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block body and return statement are unnecessary. It's asking you to change your code to this:

```
let guestBeingEdited = SJ.Event.ListItem.previouslyAddedGuests.filter(
    guest => guest.id === SJ.Event.ListItem.selectPrevGuest
);
```

Comment: I had made the mistake of keeping the semicolon. Thanks

Comment: guest => guest.id === SJ.Event.ListItem.selectPrevGuest,     comma needs to be added at last and it solves the problem